# ASP.NET - SEO-friendly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, seo

I would like to ask you guys about your opinion on SEO for services written in ASP.NET. I met an SEO specialist who says that it is almost impossible to make SEO for services/portals written in ASP.NET because Google robots don't like the pages it generates. Can you confirm or deny this theory?

Comment: Was this expert trying to sell you something? A bridge maybe?

Comment: Lol - almost. It seems we will have to throw all our open projects written in asp.net to the basket and start with PHP. He claims that web pages based on ASP.NET are slower and this way Google prefers faster PHP pages. By the way how to boost my ASP.NET web pages?

Answer (score 8):

If the portal relies heavily on query strings or improperly loaded AJAX pages, then it would be nearly impossible. But if it has friendly names, it wouldn't be too hard.

Any platform can do horribly for SEO and any platform can do miracles for SEO. It all depends on how well the application is written.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Best point ever. Both good and bad implementations will always exist, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this theory. But this being said there have been some very nice additions like the routing engine allowing you to have SEO friendly URLS and the full control over the generated ids (in ASP.NET 4.0).

Comment: A nice summary of improvements is at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/05/asp-net-4-seo-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem's not in the platform itself but rather how you use it. One major SEO rule is to have machine readable HTML code to make a semantic page and standard XHTML.

ASP.net's problem lies on the built-in components that are used in a page. When the components are rendered to HTML they generate non-standard HTML code.

The trick is to generate the data on a page using standard HTML tags and than use CSS and JavaScript to style it i.e. The data can be saved in a `RecordSet` instead of a `DataGrid` and looped over to create an HTML table.

.Net has made great improvments to the auto generated code since MVC 1.0 which creates standard XHTML.